# Java networking sending a object

Tags: java, networking

I have currently been able to send data between my server and client every frame. My problem is i want to send a one time object of a class from my server to client under the name World.(there maybe parts of past attempts in the code forgive me) Below is some portions of my code. I have tried opening another thread to send it. What is the best way i can send a object once from the Host to client? Thanks for your time

Host class

```
public class Host {

static ObjectOutputStream out;
static ObjectOutputStream worldout;
static ObjectInputStream in;
static ServerSocket server; //Server side's server
static Socket client;       //Server side client's socket
static InetAddress serverAddress;
static String serverIP;
static int port = 25566; //Client and server will connect/host on this port
public static boolean isHost = true;
ThreadSend TS;

public void start(World w){

    if(isHost){
        System.out.println("You are host");
        try {
            serverAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            serverIP = serverAddress.toString();
            System.out.println(serverIP);
            server = new ServerSocket(port, 4, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.10"));
            System.out.println("Connected! waiting for client");
            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected!");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            worldout = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            new ThreadSend(out);
            new ThreadReceive(in);

            System.out.println("Started!\nCreating game world...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

client class

```
public class Client {

static ObjectOutputStream out;
static ObjectInputStream in;
static ObjectInputStream worldin;
static Socket client;       //Server side client's socket
static String connectIP; //Client will connect to this address
static Socket socket;
static int port = 25566;
public static boolean isHost = false;
ThreadReceive TR;

public void connect(String ip){
    connectIP = ip;
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    try {
        socket = new Socket(connectIP, port);
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        new ThreadSend(out);
        new ThreadReceive(in);
        //TODO get world
        System.out.println("Started!\nCreating game world...");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

ThreadSend class

```
public class ThreadSend extends Thread {

World world;
ObjectOutputStream out;
static boolean finished;
public ThreadSend(ObjectOutputStream o){
    out = o;
    finished = false;
    start();
}

public static void done(){
    finished = true;

}

public void run(){

    while(!finished){
        try {
            Vector3f player1 = Camera.getPlayer1();
            out.writeObject(""+player1.x);
            out.writeObject(""+player1.y);
            out.writeObject(""+player1.z);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

ThreadReceive class

```
public class ThreadReceive extends Thread {

static World world;
ObjectInputStream in;
static boolean finished;
public ThreadReceive(ObjectInputStream i){
    in = i;
    finished = false;
    start();
}
public static void done(){
    finished = true;
}

public void run(){

    while(!finished){
        try {
            Gen.player2.x = Float.parseFloat((String)in.readObject());
            Gen.player2.y = -Float.parseFloat((String)in.readObject());
            Gen.player2.z = Float.parseFloat((String)in.readObject());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are using `writeObject(obj)`. using this you can write any object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is kind of hard to understand. But from looking at your code you seem to be sending player1.x/y/z as strings and what you would like to do is send the full `Vector3f` object?

since you already use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` as decorators for your socket in/out streams then you can send objects through them using writeObject and read them using readObject. You were already using them but you passed strings.

Just make sure that the objects are serializable and also both the client and the server must have the same version of the object!

Comment: im trying to send a int[][][] so i made a object of the class and am trying to send that once not everyframe.

Comment: If you want to send it once just do so, use writeObject once instead of in a while loop like you did. I'm a bit confused as to what is the problem and what you are trying to attain.

Comment: Also try to avoid writing to the same OutputStream from several threads. I'm not quite sure but I think SocketOutputStream is not thread safe. Even if it is thread safe the client will get the objects 'mixed' and might fail if it doesn't get the object it's expecting.

Comment: im getting a java.io.StreamCorrupted Exception when i try to send another variable above the while loop

Comment: my problem laid with the out.flush() command thanks for the help